# Is there a quicker way to detect UIScrollView's contentOffset/how does UIPickerView trigger feedback even at high velocities?

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipickerview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a horizontally-scrolling UICollectionView to mimic iOS's UIPickerView.  Now, I want to trigger haptic feedback when selection changes just like UIPickerView does.

The problem is that when you scroll at high speeds, scrollViewDidScroll isn't called quickly enough.

Currently, I'm checking the x offset of the collection view and triggering haptic feedback when the x offset is a multiple of the cells' width (12pt), but when the x offset jumps by more than 12, feedback is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to provide feedback when the offset is an exact multiple of the cell's width, provide feedback when the "current cell" changes.

Keep a "current cell" (index) class-level variable:

```
var currentCellIndex: Int = 0

let cellWidth: CGFloat = 12.0  // or however you get it
```

on scrolling, get the "new" cell:

```
    let newCellIndex: Int = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / cellWidth)

    if newCellIndex != currentCellIndex {
        // provide feedback
        currentCellIndex = newCellIndex
    }
```

So, at start, `contentOffset.x` will be equal to `0`, and `currentCellIndex` will be `0`. As the user scrolls (very, very slowly), you'll get:

```
Int( 1.0 / 12.0) // equals 0, no change
Int( 2.0 / 12.0) // equals 0, no change
Int( 3.0 / 12.0) // equals 0, no change
Int( 4.0 / 12.0) // equals 0, no change
etc ...
Int(12.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, so newIndex != curIndex... provide feedback and update curIndex
Int(13.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, no change
Int(14.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, no change
Int(15.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, no change
Int(16.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, no change
etc ...
Int(24.0 / 12.0) // equals 2, so newIndex != curIndex... provide feedback and update curIndex
```

When the user scrolls *quickly*:

```
Int( 9.0 / 12.0) // equals 0, no change
Int(16.0 / 12.0) // equals 1, so newIndex != curIndex... provide feedback and update curIndex
Int(31.0 / 12.0) // equals 2, so newIndex != curIndex... provide feedback and update curIndex
Int(64.0 / 12.0) // equals 5, so newIndex != curIndex... provide feedback and update curIndex
etc ...
```

Comment: I tried a similar solution before but there's still a problem with triggering haptic feedback (perhaps warranting a different question altogether).

In the last section of your code, when the index jumps from 2 to 5, ideally, I would trigger haptic feedback 3 times. But I wasn't able to get it to trigger when put in a loop, even if I use a delay of ~0.2 sec between each feedback.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want that much feedback? Looking at, for example, setting an alarm time on the default Clock app... I can scroll very quickly, jumping from 2 to 14 (the minutes part of the picker), and I only hear 3 "clicks." If you really want feedback for every cell that is passed, then you'd have to do `num = newIdx - curIdx` and then call your feedback that many times.

Comment: UX-wise: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
Code-wise: I would at least like the option to be able to see what I like from the user's perspective.

On the clock app, fast drags do seem to skip, but a fast flick has satisfying continuous feedback. Maybe I should just leave this as is for dragging and try triggering feedback X amount of times based on a flick's velocity.